# Twitter Bootstrap make collapsible menu link unclickable (if JS enabled)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to turn the menu (essentially a link `<a>`) in my navbar to a collapsible menu using [Twitter Bootstrap's Collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

The collapsible menu is functional, but the problem is that the menu link is clickable i.e. when the menu is clicked, instead of it opening up, I am taken to the linked page.

As of now, I am using `onclick="return false;"` to disable the default behavior of the menu link (as seen below) i.e. make it unclickable.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <!-- [...] --> </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <!-- [...] -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>

                <!-- COLLAPSIBLE MENU LINK -->
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-searchform" class="collapsed" href="/search/" onclick="return false;"><b class="wtnerd-icomoon icon-search"></b><span class="sr-only">Search</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>

                <div id="nav-searchform" class="collapse" role="menu">
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="input-group" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                        <label for="s" class="sr-only">Search for:</label>
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" id="s" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I want the menus to be functional even with JavaScript disabled which is why I am not simply using `href="#"`.

So, the question is, does Twitter Bootstrap has a built-in way to deal with my problem so that I don't have to use the `onclick` JavaScript attribute in HTML? If not, is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is fine the only other alternative that I can think of is using `preventDefault`

`$("myElement").on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: Works great, except your code is missing a semi-colon. :) Also, isn't `e.stopPropagation();` necessary? http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can add something like this in your ready function

```
$("a[data-toggle='collapse']").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So you don't have to add the onclick attribute..